# JavaScript join multiple arrays confusion?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, join

According to W3Schools , the join() function is defined as

"*The join() method joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.
The elements will be separated by a specified separator. The default separator is comma (,)*."

However,If i try joining two arrays together using the join() function , it produces an output that I do not seem to comprehend.Can anyone explain?
Here is the sample code :

```
<body>

<p>Click the button to join the array elements into a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    var food = ["Chicken","Fish","Lamb","Prawns"];
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = fruits.join(food);
}
</script>
</body>
```

**JSFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/gf84ee9y/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are joining one array and passing in another array as the separator:

```
fruits.join(food);
```

The output is actually to be expected, for each 'fruit' you have, you put the whole food array in between them.

If you want to merge the two arrays, use `concat`:

```
var newArray = fruits.concat(food);
```

Now you can join the newArray and it will have only one copy of each element from each array.

[Working example with concat](https://jsfiddle.net/gf84ee9y/1/)

Comment: This is the correct answer, join needs a string as an argument to be used as separator like " " (space) or "|" , but passing array in itself violate the purpose of join method.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use concat. See the [documents on concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
x.innerHTML = fruits.concat(food);
```

Answer (score 1):

Join is not what you are looking for, concat is:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat